# Affine manifolds which are not euclidean manifolds.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, compact-manifolds, homogeneous-spaces

> I want to find a differentiable $n$-dimensional compact manifold $M$ which can be endowed with an affine structure but cannot be endowed with a euclidean structure.

An affine (resp. euclidean) structure is a [geometric structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(G,X)-manifold) with $X=\Bbb R^n$ and $G$ is the group of affine (resp. euclidean) transformations of $\Bbb R^n$.

I would like to find such a manifold for every possible dimension $n\geq 1$. I know that in dimension $1$ and $2$, such a manifold doesn't exist, since the only affine manifolds in that case are the circle, the torus and the Klein bottle and all of them are euclidean manifolds.

In dimension $3$, I think that $S^1\times S^2$ is an example. It is an affine manifold since it is diffeomorphic to the quotient 
$$\Bbb R^3-0/x\sim 2x.$$
However I don't really know how to prove that $S^1\times S^2$ has no euclidean structure (maybe we can use some theorem of Thurston about geometries of $3$-manifolds but it seems to be a "big tool")

In dimension $n\geq 4$, maybe $S^1\times S^{n-1}\simeq \Bbb R^n-0/x\sim 2x$ could be an example, but again I don't know how to prove that this manifold doesn't admit a euclidean structure.

> Is there an elementary proof that these compact affine manifolds don't have euclidean structures? Are there some better examples?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each Euclidean manifold $M$ admits a flat Riemannian metric (obtained by pull-back of the flat Riemannian metric on $E^n$ via coordinate charts of the Euclidean atlas). If $M$ is compact, the metric is complete ([Hopf-Rinow theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf%E2%80%93Rinow_theorem)) , so is its lift to the universal covering space $X$ of $M$ (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1502865/the-covering-manifold-of-a-complete-riemannian-manifold-is-complete)). By [Cartan-Killing-Hopf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing%E2%80%93Hopf_theorem), each simply connected complete flat $n$-dimensional manifold (such as $X$) is isometric to the Euclidean space $E^n$. In particular, its higher homotopy groups ($\pi_k(X)$, $k\ge 2$) vanish. Thus, your examples (covered by $S^{n-1}\times {\mathbb R}$, $n\ge 3$) do not admit Euclidean structures since $\pi_{n-1}\cong {\mathbb Z}$). These are the simplest examples. I can give you examples of aspherical affine manifolds not admitting Euclidean structures (say, product of genus 2 surface and the circle), but proofs are more complicated. Instead of higher homotopy groups you would use [Bieberbach's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2277650/bieberbach-theorem) that the fundamental group of every complete flat Riemannian manifold is virtually abelian.

In the answer I assumed that you know basic Riemannian geometry and some algebraic topology; if you do not, I suggest do Carmo's book "Riemannian Geometry" for Riemannian geometry and, say, Hatcher, for algebraic topology.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. I've began studying Riemannian geometry recently but it's fine I get the arguments. In the meantime I read about Bieberbach theorem which says that every compact Euclidean manifold is finitely
covered by a flat torus. It solves the problem but it's just a more complicated way to say that the universal cover of a compact Euclidean manifold is $E^n$.